# Python program closes quickly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple code to print , "hello world" in Python.
As I execute it , the terminal window pops up and closes within a second , even before I can read the message.
**Possibly , what is wrong** ?

Comment: (Probably) nothing is wrong; the terminal window closes when the program finishes.

Comment: Please read some book about python, search before you ask a question. Nothing went wrong. It just printed your text and closed the terminal because it is finished.

Comment: [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).

Comment: You haven't mentioned the operating system and how are you executing it. I'm not having this problem on Linux, so how do I reproduce it? :-D Also how about doing some research first. If I search "Python program closes quickly" with Google, some interesting results pop at the top e.g. [How can I stop python.exe from closing immediately after I get an output?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3591807/12892) or [How do I prevent my Python 2.6 application from automatically closing once reaching the end of code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2322868/12892). Maybe you should create a canonical question.

Comment: Errata: **we** the Stack Overflow community, not you the one who asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the program in windows, as far as there are two workarounds:

- Run the program in command prompt (cmd.exe, powershell) instead of double clicking the script file.
- Modify the script to include [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) at the end of the script (to make the script wait for user input)

Answer (score 0):

You could make it to ask you a question like :

```
var = input("Please enter something: ")
```

So it won't immediately close.

Comment: The question is tagged `python-3.x`; no `raw_input`, but `input`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows and do not want to change your program, start it by double-clicking a batch file, called `RUNHELLO.BAT` containing this:

```
python helloworld.py
PAUSE
```

Answer (score -1):

first I think you should wirte "Hello world" in this section:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Hello World!");
```

then you should run this command "python helloworld.py" in terminal.

Hope help you.