# My comand prompt exits right after I test my code

Tags: python

Right after I start my PYTHON code my comand prompt exits.I can't even test it out or see the result becaues it exits too fast.Any help?

Comment: Tmp Solution: Open in IDLE and press F5 or add `input()` at end of code

Comment: Are you running it from a terminal, command prompt, or just clicking on a file?

Comment: Just add this to the end of your program: `raw_input('Press Enter to exit')`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322868/how-do-i-prevent-my-python-application-from-automatically-closing-once-reaching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

to the end of your file. It will wait for you to press Enter.